# SQL query and PHP sorting

Tags: php, sql

I have two SQL tables:

`users` from which I need all email addresess which looks like:

```
---------------------
| id | email | pass |
```

and `user_answers` from which I need all unique question ids which looks like:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| id | question_id | user_id | date_registrated |
```

Each user can answer few times on one question, for short I need:

```
array => $users_array[0] = array($user[email], $user[uniqe_ids], $user[date_registrated])
$users_array[1] = ...
```

How can I do it? I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `".USERS_TABLE."` AS u LEFT JOIN `".QUESTION_TABLE."` AS c ON u.id = c.user_id
WHERE user_admin =".$user_id." ORDER BY u.email
```

and tried to sort it, bu with no effect.

Comment: typo: `ORDER` not `RDER`

Comment: What is the error? You spelled ORDER wrong btw.

Comment: I didn't understand your question sorry, each user can enter multiple answers for a question. then, which one do you pick as the answer?

Comment: From where the column _user_admin_ came from?

Comment: theres no error, I had just mistyped order

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select u.id,u.email,u.user_answers, c.question_id, c.date_registered
from USERS_TABLE AS u LEFT JOIN QUESTION_TABLE AS c 
ON u.id = c.user_id
where u.id = ".$user_id." 
ORDER BY u.email asc
```

But this doesn't give anything meaningful to your scenario. kindly explain the scenario clearly.